# Reasoning behind why 1 is not shown to be in range of f(x) by the method below

Tags: functions

Suppose we need to find range of $f(x)$ = $\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-2x-3} $, $x\neq 3,-1$

> One way would be to express x as a function of y and find the domain of that function   , after solving using quadratic formula we arrived at $x = \frac{2y \pm 2√(4y^2 -2y-1)}{2(y-1)}$ , from this we can observed spliting into two functions for each + and - sign  domain of anyone should be $y \neq 1$ and $4y^2-2y-1 \geq 0$ , on solving we get range of original function to be $(-\infty ,\frac{1-√5}{4} ]$ $\cup$ $[\frac{1+√5}{4}, \infty )$ - {${1}$} , now the problem is that actually $y = 1$ should also be in the domain as we can see when we set that $f(x) = 1$ we get $x = -2$ which is in domain of $f(x)$  , But then why the method is not giving the 1 as in the range then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quadratic formula gives solutions to $ax^2+bx+c=0$ assuming $a\ne0$. If $a$ depends on a parameter (in this case $y$), you should separately consider the possibility where $a=0$.

Comment: Sir i think i understood , by the way is it a conincidence that if we take limit as a approaches zero to the quadratic formula we get x = -c/b same as if we had get without qudraric formula ? Or there is a deeper connection ?

Comment: And in general most books just say to just use discriminamt >= 0 for getting  range , is it because the coefficeint of x^2 which can make a possible range value , like in our case (y-1) will always be inside the range we got from the discriminant >=0 condition ?

Comment: It's not a coincidence - taking the limit as $a\to0$ works because the graph of $y=ax^2+bx+c$ changes continuously as $a$ varies. When $a$ approaches 0, the parabola gets flatter/wider until at $a=0$ it becomes a straight line. The limit of one of the parabola's x-intercepts is the line's x-intercept.

Comment: And yeah, the set of all parameter values that make $b^2-4ac\ge0$ includes those that make $a=0$, because if $a=0$ then $b^2-4ac=b^2\ge0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot understood everything